# How to decode socket response?

Tags: ruby, decode

I am try to decode socket response from web source, but I can to decode only 50% of message.
It looks strange, because it should be a full message decompress, if it can decompress some socket response, but maybe I wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
require "faye/websocket"
require "eventmachine"
require "permessage_deflate"
require 'zlib'
require 'stringio'

EM.run do
  ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new("wss://wss.winline.ru/data_ng?", [], :extensions => [PermessageDeflate])

  ws.on :open do |event|
    p [:open]
    ws.send "lang"
    ws.send "AQ==" 
    ws.send "data" 
    ws.send "WINLINE" 
    ws.send "getdate" 
    ws.send "no_fordata" 

  end

  ws.on :message do |event|
    gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(event.data.pack('C*')))    
    puts gz.read
  end

  ws.on :close do |event|
    p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
    ws = nil
  end
end
```

I have receive the following data:

```
�$��$^���60.5
�$��$^��62.5'!�$i#�$^����31.5�I�$�6�$^���9.5�3�$^���11.5�   �$^��10�3�$$W�$^����80:3ূ$�m���&ާ�$�m�id�rݧ�$�m�t
 
�$''�=�v�p��a��0ȣc�Cincinnati BearcatsDetroit Mercy Titans��}$1'':%���}$1''�G���}$1'n|
```

As u can see, some parts of the message are decodable and other is still not.

Without decompress, I have this msg from sock:

```
[242, 204, 179, 144, 33, 112, 239, 219, 8, 118, 124, 89, 134, 218, 170, 173, 183, 173, 126, 59, 167, 131, 63, 254, 48, 115, 255, 123, 7, 161, 157, 64, 184, 79, 95, 202, 7, 203, 254, 172, 245, 49, 72, 63, 3, 5, 128, 62, 243, 77, 202, 4, 219, 80, 245, 92, 169, 237, 174, 85, 242, 165, 252, 180, 73, 54, 149, 19, 245, 163, 88, 212, 49, 186, 65, 111, 156, 215, 136, 53, 70, 54, 205, 33, 147, 72, 255, 36, 246, 167, 135, 253, 65, 163, 224, 36, 28, 78, 38, 227, 165, 7, 191, 246, 98, 255, 235, 195, 126, 55, 101, 38, 246, 68, 188, 252, 63, 92, 112, 93, 239, 36, 118, 2, 0]
```

I think, this source are using pako to compress their data socket.

Comment: What message? Please give us enough detail to at least understand the issue, if not reproduce it.

Comment: Please edit the question. Don't dump it in a comment.

Comment: @tadman Ok, will do it now